# Using python how to convert hex byte string to string of hex intergers in flipped order

Tags: python, hex

From:
**25f207f2**8332c7da539dd2539230a7aad975f907a93d924b4b037abacde677f0f71f75cc250df2e4dd2be3e9**7a60f289**

To:
**0x7a60f289**, 0xdd2be3e9, 0x250df2e4, 0xf71f75cc, 0xcde677f0, 0x4b037aba, 
    0xa93d924b, 0xd975f907, 0x9230a7aa, 0x539dd253, 0x8332c7da, **0x25f207f2**

Comment: I know what he is asking, between the title and the comment it isn't that hard to figure out. A better explanation in the questions body would be nice though.

Comment: @Loocid: Agreed, voted to reopen but downvoted. :)

Comment: Excellent just what I needed.  Here is the preamble on the problem: Given a string of hex bytes convert to a string of hex unsigned ints in reverse word order.  I just figured an example is worth a 1000 words!

Answer (score 2):

Just slice the string into chunks and reverse the order adding `0x` with str.format:

```
s = "25f207f28332c7da539dd2539230a7aad975f907a93d924b4b037abacde677f0f71f75cc250df2e4dd2be3e97a60f289"

print(["0x{}".format(s[i-8:i]) for i in range(len(s), 0, -8) ])
['0x7a60f289', '0xdd2be3e9', '0x250df2e4', '0xf71f75cc', '0xcde677f0', '0x4b037aba', '0xa93d924b', '0xd975f907', '0x9230a7aa', '0x539dd253', '0x8332c7da', '0x25f207f2']
```

If you actually want decimals:

```
print([int("0x{}".format(s[i-8:i]),16) for i in range(len(s), 0, -8) ])
[2053173897, 3710641129, 621671140, 4146034124, 3454433264, 1258519226, 2839384651, 3648387335, 2452662186, 1402851923, 2201143258, 636618738]
```

Comment: How did you answer this question after it was closed and before it was reopened?

Comment: @abarnert, I had the answer ready for a while, I did not see the question was closed until I actually submitted it, I have no idea how the answer actually went through.

Comment: I was just curious about the mechanics of how it went through… but not curious enough to ask on Meta about it. :)

Comment: @abarnert. lol indeed, well it is past my bedtime so I definitely won't be investigating :)

Comment: `[ s[i:i+8] for i in xrange(len(s)-8,-1,-8)]` instead of `reversed([s[i:i+8] for i in range(0,len(s),8)])`

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM., `[ s[i-8:i] for i range(len(s), 0, -8) ]` instead.

Comment: @Anzel yep, it's better ;-)

Comment: Another clumsy way is to `print([hex(int(s[i-8:i], 16)) for i in range(len(s), 0, -8)])`

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM., yep, a much better idea, in my defence it was very late!

Comment: @Anzel, robbed your code

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, lol sure unfortunately I can't upvote you twice ;-)

Comment: Excellent just what I needed.  Here is the preamble on the problem: Given a string of hex bytes convert to a string of hex unsigned ints in reverse word order.  I just figured an example is worth a 1000 words!